# Wepshere application cluster and MQ Message

Tags: ibm-mq

I have Webshpere Cluster with 4 JVM. JVM1 , JVM2 , JVM3 and JVM4 , all are using single Queue MGR1 with Single Queue.

1. If a message put on queue using jvm1 bootstrup address, Is it available to to other JVMs as well for processing.
2. What if a load balancer put on front of JVM1 , JVM2 , JVM3 and JVM4 , Is it make any difference from point1.
3. Should a MQ cluster with Gateway Mgr3 and sub queue mgr Mgr1 and Mgr 2 should be used to process the message parally.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. The message will be available to the first consumer that recevies it. A queue works like a load balancer when multiple consumers are reading from it.
2. Not sure how a load balancer is going to affect MQ at all. You are talking about a HTTP load balancer right?
3. MQ cluster and multiple QMGRS have other reasons, such as distributing load across several physical machines, separating security and business level domains as well as administrational purposes.